# Canada immigration from USA for an indian

Tags: visa, immigration, canada

I am on H1B visa in the USA, and I want to move to Canada, what is the process for doing so and if anybody knows any consultant who can do that for me, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Canada has a web site for this:

http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/

There, you can check your eligibility and learn about the procedural requirements.

Recommendations for specific service providers are beyond the scope of this site.